# Send javamail from Office365 v.s. gmail: what differs?

Tags: java, email, office365, jakarta-mail

I try to send e-mail from my company that uses Office365.
I use javax.mail to do it. Here is my method:
UPD: the original method is kept below. Here is an edited method, still fault:

```
public void composeAndSend(ByteArrayOutputStream baos) {
String to =   "nameto@gmail.com";
String from = "namefrom@company.com";
String host = "smtp.office365.com";
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
Session session=Session.getInstance(properties);
session.setDebug(true);
try {
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
  message.setSubject("Test message");
  message.setText(baos.toString());
  System.out.println("Sending message...");
  Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
  t.connect(host, 587, from, "password_of_office365_user");
  t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
  t.close();
}catch (MessagingException mex) {
  mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

The first version:

```
public void composeAndSend(ByteArrayOutputStream baos) {
String to =   "nameto@gmail.com";
String from = "namefrom@company.com";
String host = "smtp.office365.com";   // tried also "ssl://smtp.office365.com"
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
  @Override
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication( from, "password_of_office365_user" );
  }
};
Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, authenticator);
//Session session=Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator); no difference...
try {
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
  message.setSubject("Test message");
  message.setText(baos.toString());
  System.out.println("Sending message...");
  Transport.send(message);
}catch (MessagingException mex) {
  mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

I get **javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.office365.com;**
But when I **exchange places** of sender and receiver - everything is OK. So I suppose the settings are OK too.
How it comes that the Google server accepts the message and sends my e-mail but Office365 does not?

Comment: First, fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Switching the from and to addresses and nothing else shouldn't make any difference.  The problem is that your machine can't lookup the host name smtp.office365.com.  Try the [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug) in the JavaMail FAQ.  Post the results.  Also, do **not** set `mail.smtp.ssl` when using port 587.

Comment: First, thank you for the link. I use getInstance() now though I still don't see any Transport.send method that uses authentication. Should I create a child class to implement a new method?  Second, I try to check connectivity to the server. The ping is OK. The telnet: "could not resolve smtp.office365.com/25: Name or service not known" (the same w. 487 port). Does it mean my networking is bad? At last, I switched on debug with session.setDebug(true) and it says: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL false (???) - and the Exception is still Unknown SMTP host...

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  This [Transport.send method](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Transport.html#send-javax.mail.Message-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) has been in JavaMail since 1.5.  telnet does not take the port number as "/25" added on to the host name, it takes it as a second parameter: "telnet smtp.office365.com 25".  It's still most likely that there's a proxy preventing you from connecting directly.  Do you need to configure a proxy when using a web browser?

Comment: Transport class is bytecode 48.0, Java 1.4. Where is it from? Don't know. About telnet: it shows /25, I put port number with space. And I don't use proxy, AFAIK. My Linux system has been installed by me alone and I never used configured proxy.

Comment: Get the [current version of JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).  Are you behind a firewall on a corporate network?

Comment: Yes! It works! I just replaced JavaMail to the latest version and returned Transport.send(message, username password) - excluded using Authenticator. Thank you very much, @Bill Shannon for your help!